# How to change Spock test template in IntellijIdea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, spock

It could be handy to know from where Spock tests are generating and have the possibility to add something there.

For now, if to press *(Cmd/Ctrl)+Shift+t* you can see something like this
[image]

with possibility to change base class and generate some test methods. But how can I add, for example, autogenerated string.

`WheelGameCreator target = new WheelGameCreator()`

to each my test?

I've found some templates in File and Code Templates, but changes there have no effect on my newly generated tests.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is the Spock Test Method template in the "code" pane
[image]

In case you change the template here, you may use it when generating the Spock tests in the following way:
[image]

Comment: Yes, but I need to have control over whole test class, not only test method

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I have since found that the template that you have set up will only work when you go through the

New... Spock Specification context menu, (like below)

[image: New Spock Spec]

In order to have this show when you create a new test class from the class using the dialog you have shown, you need to edit the groovy class template. (After all, the Spock specification is just a groovy class).

Thankfully, with the help of velocity templates I was able to create a conditional on that, to help detect if it is a normal groovy class or a Spock specification.

[image: Groovy Class template]

You can see from this, I test the name ends with Spec (As that is a naming convention I use for all my Spock Specification classes) and if it does output one template, otherwise it will output a different template.

You will also notice that I don't import, or extend Specification in this as the test creation will do this automatically.